# Почему некоторые столбцы в таблице выделены красным? phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Использую phpMyAdmin и заметил, что некоторые столбцы в таблицах красные а не белые. В интернете ничего не нашел на тему "красные столбцы в MySql".
[Скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F83tj.png)

Comment: потому что красные они не в mysql, а в phpmyadmin

Comment: розовым там похоже выделяется поле. которое показывается при редактировании связанных значений. то есть в выпадающем списке будет показан не ключ, а значение из этого столбца.

Comment: Это можно изменить ?

Comment: что именно? цвет другим сделать или убрать? отредактируйте стили пхпмайадмина, если они доступны вам.

Comment: Изменить ссылку чтобы показывала значение из другого столбца таблицы.

Comment: можно, должна быть кнопка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

согласно [документации](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=pink#how-do-i-create-a-relation-in-designer)

> To select relation, click: The display column is shown in pink. To set/unset a column as the display column, click the „Choose column to display“ icon, then click on the appropriate column name.

розовым цветом выделяется столбец, значения которого отображаются в связных списках.

чтобы выбрать другой столбец в качестве отображаемого при редактировании связных записей, надо использовать кнопку "Choose column to display" (где она не знаю, у меня phpmyadmin нет)

Comment: Эта кнопка в меню конструктора. Там есть кнопка "Выбор отображаемого столбца"